# How to use inherited service declared in the constructor in angular

Tags: angular, inheritance, constructor

I try to create a `baseComponent`, which will be then extended by many other components.

I'm trying to pass a service through `super()` but I get a `Cannot read properties of undefined`

What I tried

```js
@Directive()
export class BaseComponent { 
  constructor(public componentService: baseService) {
     console.log(this.componentService.foo.bar) // Cannot read properties of undefined "foo"
  }
}
```

```js
@Directive()
export class ExtendedComponent extends BaseComponent { 
  constructor(public componentService: ExtendedService) {
     console.log(this.componentService.foo.bar) // Cannot read properties of undefined "foo"
  }
}
```

The `ExtendedService` does extend from `BaseService` and have the `foo.bar` object.
I know this would work, If I would do that in the `ngOnInit()` but this isn't the objective hier.

Where is my error ? I'm missing something, but cannot find what...

Comment: First of all, add `extends BaseComponent` to your ExtendedComponent

Comment: @igor_c Thx, It it in my code, I did forget to apply it here. I did the fix